# Use foreach on resources? (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, foreach, resources

Hey guys I was wondering how I could use foreach on a few specified resources...

for example, if i had these four resources, how could I cycle through the same action on each resource using foreach:

```
test.Properties.Resources.file1
test.Properties.Resources.file2
test.Properties.Resources.file3
test.Properties.Resources.file4
```

Comment: Welcome.  Your question is essentially a set of requirements.  [ask]

Answer (score 4):

Try something like this

```
    ResourceSet resourceSet = Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetResourceSet(CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture, true, true);
      foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in resourceSet)
        {
            string resourceKey = entry.Key.ToString();
            object resource = entry.Value;
        }
```